# Filtering out data such that we drop rows under condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of courses people have taken, I want to drop the courses that have less than `N` participants. I was able to achieve this like so

```
## Filter out courses with less than n participants 
N = 50
a = df_knet.groupby('ktrngtt_training_title').agg({'alias':'count'})
a = a.reset_index()
a = a[a['alias'] > N]
course_list = a['ktrngtt_training_title'].tolist()
df_knet_subset = df_knet[df_knet['ktrngtt_training_title'].isin(course_list)]
```

But I feel like there may be a more efficient way of achieving this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is a sample dataframe

```
d = {'ktrngtt_training_title': {273461: 'C2CS: Customer Obsession Resources',
  56871: 'excel class',
  339853: 'Assimilate class',
  280102: 'WW Foundations Speculatie Empathie',
  116610: 'Basic Wireless CLI troubleshooting',
  177462: 'linux class',
  32114: 'windows class',
  217588: 'FC LITE Certification',
  346506: 'ARU-Nike Racklight Replacement Procedures',
  252576: 'CSSM for Managers - AVOC 2.0'},
'alias': {273461: 'dercla',
  56871: 'sammb',
  339853: 'boshas',
  280102: 'azzmo',
  116610: 'sahmeh',
  177462: 'kggure',
  32114: 'vaia',
  217588: 'wbh',
  346506: 'wiasw',
  252576: 'chaaor'}}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: please provide a sample df, preferably with a piece of code that can be copy-pasted to recreate it, without having to type it out again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have used your data to simulated a working dataframe
- no intermediary **list**
- **count** is required to calculate number of participants.  Fundamentally it is same method

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ktrngtt_training_title": np.random.choice(
            [
                "C2CS: Customer Obsession Resources",
                "excel class",
                "Assimilate class",
                "WW Foundations Speculatie Empathie",
                "Basic Wireless CLI troubleshooting",
                "linux class",
                "windows class",
                "FC LITE Certification",
                "ARU-Nike Racklight Replacement Procedures",
                "CSSM for Managers - AVOC 2.0",
            ],
            500,
        ),
        "alias": np.random.choice(list("abcde"), 500),
    }
)


N = 50
df.loc[
    df["ktrngtt_training_title"].isin(
        (df.groupby("ktrngtt_training_title").agg({"alias": "count"}) > N)
        .pipe(lambda d: d.loc[d["alias"]])
        .index
    )
]
```

Comment: I provided some data. This method you have will do the same thing though? As in drop course where the participants that are less than `N`?

Comment: oops - I have got your data structure wrong.  have updated answer.  The approach is slightly modified, but fundamentally the same